# Div width to total table row

Tags: css

I am trying the have/style a DIV which resides in the last table cell and have detailed information of the record displayed in table-row

The structure looks like

```
<tr>
 <td>Saturday 21.11.2015 </td>
 <td>Frankfurt </td>
 <td>London </td>
 <td> <a href="#">**+ show details**</a>
    <div class="toggle-details">....</div>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Now I need that if the user clicks on the link the div with class name `toggle-details` should be toggled and it should be as wide as the complete table-row. not the cell

Comment: Using pure javascript ? Using Jquery ? Only in CSS ? What did you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it.

Set `position: relative` on  your parent table and then use 
`position: absolute` on the hidden `div` that you will toggle to show/hide.

The `.panel` block element will take on the width of the table (rows) and you can adjust the offsets to position it as needed.

The trick is to set the left and right offsets only.  If you omit the `top` offset, it will default to the position of the element if it were not absolutely positioned.  This allows you to get staggered positioning for the 
hidden panel if this is what you need.

Alternatively, if you set the `top` offset, then all the panels would be positioned in the same positioned and they would overlap each other.

You could also try setting `position: relative` on the `tr` elements, but this breaks in Chrome (but works in Firefox and IE).

```css
table {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  position: relative;
}
.panel {
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%; /* adjust as needed */
  right: -25%; /* use -value of left to keep full row width */
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First Cell is Long</td>
    <td>
      <a>Show Div Link</a>
      <div class="panel">(1) Hidden div/panel to be toggled. and text
      no longer than the parent table.</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>First Cell is Long</td>
    <td>
      <a>Show Div Link</a>
      <div class="panel">(2) Hidden div/panel to be toggled. and text
      no longer than the parent table.</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>First Cell is Long</td>
    <td>
      <a>Show Div Link</a>
      <div class="panel">(3) Hidden div/panel to be toggled. and text
      no longer than the parent table.</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but unfortunately will not work as tr ignores the relative position attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for this:

Write position relative for the `tr` elements, by this mode you can make the div in position absolute:

```
tr {
    position: relative;
}
.toggle-details {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

See it working:

http://jsfiddle.net/6epnonge/

Comment: Thank you for the response, but unfortunately will not work as tr ignores the relative position attribute.

Comment: @user3733648 it doesn't. See the fiddle. It works. How are you making to avoid it?

Comment: please check all the 3 DIVs are displayed over one another, atleast in chrome and IE

Comment: Your only solution is with javascript. The best way is adding a new row and show and hide when the button is clicked

Comment: There is a way of working around the Chome `tr` issue with `position: relative` by omitting the `top` offset, see my posted solution below.

Comment: Yes, but it takes the relative top where it is. Then, by this mode, maybe the div doesn't fit exactly with the top line of the row. But if it fits with the OP requirements, good appointment.